# How to migrate storage from a default pallet instance to an actual one

Tags: pallet, storage, instantiable

I'm about to introduce several instances of a pallet that was previously used as a default instance. The question is: how do I migrate the storage of `pallet_bags_list` to `pallet_bags_list::<Instance1>`. <s>Or does it happen automatically for the first instance?</s> It seems like this does not happen automatically, because a `DefaultInstance` has an empty prefix, named instances have their name as prefix.

Some context could be found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/74b6fba024eeaae38b78a143a2c70358dec22450/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1639) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple, the pallet storage is prefixed according to how it's defined in `construct_runtime!`.

So in order to migrate from

```
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = node_primitives::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system,
        Utility: pallet_utility,
        Uniques: pallet_uniques,
        TransactionStorage: pallet_transaction_storage,
        BagsList: pallet_bags_list,
        ....
    }
);
```

to

```
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = node_primitives::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system,
        Utility: pallet_utility,
        Uniques: pallet_uniques,
        TransactionStorage: pallet_transaction_storage,
        VoterBagsList: pallet_bags_list::<Instance1>,
        ....
    }
);
```

We simply need to use [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c8653447fc8ef8d95a92fe164c96dffb37919e85/frame/support/src/storage/migration.rs#L363) function. A full example would look like this:

```
    pub fn migrate<T: Config, P: GetStorageVersion + PalletInfoAccess, N: AsRef<str>>(
        old_pallet_name: N,
    ) -> Weight {
        let old_pallet_name = old_pallet_name.as_ref();
        let new_pallet_name = <P as PalletInfoAccess>::name();

        if new_pallet_name == old_pallet_name {
            log!(warn, "new bags-list name is equal to the old one, no need to migrate");
            return 0
        }

        if StorageVersion::<T>::get() == Releases::V10_0_0 {
            move_pallet(old_pallet_name.as_bytes(), new_pallet_name.as_bytes());
            StorageVersion::<T>::put(Releases::V11_0_0);
            <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockWeights::get().max_block
        } else {
            log!(warn, "v11::migrate should be removed.");
            T::DbWeight::get().reads(1)
        }
    }
```

Where `old_pallet_name` would be `BagsList`.

Answer (score 1):

Each pallet in a runtime has an index associate with it. When an extrinsic is scale encoded, this index is the first byte that identifies which pallet it belongs to. (The next byte identifies which pallet's `Call` variant is being called).

In the linked `construct_runtime!` there are no explicit indexes, so the first pallet will be 0 and its enumerated from there on. If people add new pallets / pallet instances on the end then nothing disrupts the existing index numbers. However for production chains it's recommended to explicitly specify the pallet indexes your using (E.g. [statemint](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/15d4f8b3be52ca530a4b2c3bf2c5d7fce2f1ab17/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L583)).

The pallet's storage is prefixed by the pallet's index to make its self contained.